# Have HTML form with text and checkbox - how do I post checkbox responses to Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

I have an HTML form with several various text and checkbox fields.  I have the text fields posting to the correct table but the checkbox responses are not posting at all (intended to post to a separate table).

**Here's my HTML form:**

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <?php include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\paxdb\head.php'; 
    include 'config/menu.php';?> 
    <div id="dataentry">
    <!--This section is the demographic text field area-->
    <form method="post" action="dataentered.php">
    First Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="First_Name" name="First_Name"/></br>
    </br>
    Last Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="Last_Name" name="Last_Name"/></br>
    </br>
    E-mail:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="email" name="email"/></br>
    </br>

    <!--This section is the age range checkbox selection area-->
    <p><u><b>Age Range</b></u></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="20-25" value="1"/>&nbsp;20-25</br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="26-30" value="1"/>&nbsp;26-30</br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="31-35" value="1"/>&nbsp;31-35</br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="36-40" value="1"/>&nbsp;36-40</br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="41-45" value="1"/>&nbsp;41-45</br>
    </div>

<p><u><b>What City or region would you like to visit in the US or Canada?:</b></u></p>
<textarea name="comment2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>       
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**and here is the PHP code I am trying but only have the text fields working:**

```
<html>
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="someusername";
$password="somepassword";
$dbname="somedbname";

$dbc = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$dbc)
{
    die('Error connecting to MySQL server' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbc);

//send pax data to pax database table
$first_name=$_POST['First_Name'];   
$last_name=$_POST['Last_Name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO pax (First_Name, Last_Name, email)
VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email')"); 

//send age checkbox data to age database table
$age = $_POST['age'];
foreach($age as $range) mysql_query("INSERT INTO age ($age) VALUES ('$range')") or die (mysql_error());


mysql_close($dbc);
```

**Any help is appreciated.**

**EDIT To clarify:** the mysql table 'age' has the following fields: 
age_id (key),
pax_id (index for the text field data at the beginning of the form),
20-25
26-30
and so on through the age ranges.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Your inputs are pointless - IDs are not sent in the httpd request, so all you'll get are a series of `1` values, not the 20-25 type values. e.g. if any checkbox is selected, then the values you're sending imply that ALL checkboxes are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the code for you

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<?php include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\paxdb\head.php'; 
include 'config/menu.php';?> 
<div id="dataentry">
<!--This section is the demographic text field area-->
<form method="post" action="dataentered.php">
First Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="First_Name" name="First_Name"/></br>
</br>
Last Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="Last_Name" name="Last_Name"/></br>
</br>
E-mail:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="email" name="email"/></br>
</br>

<!--This section is the age range checkbox selection area-->
<p><u><b>Age Range</b></u></p>
<!-- Change your checkbox value -->
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="20-25" value="20-25"/>&nbsp;20-25</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="26-30" value="26-30"/>&nbsp;26-30</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="31-35" value="31-35"/>&nbsp;31-35</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="36-40" value="36-40"/>&nbsp;36-40</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" id="41-45" value="41-45"/>&nbsp;41-45</br>
</div>

<p><u><b>What City or region would you like to visit in the US or Canada?:</b></u></p>
<textarea name="comment2" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>       
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You cannot insert the array($age) directly into the database as you have done in INSERT statement...One of the solution that i did is convert the array into string and then insert it into database as shown...

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="someusername";
$password="somepassword";
$dbname="somedbname";

$dbc = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$dbc)
{
    die('Error connecting to MySQL server' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbc);

//send pax data to pax database table
$first_name=$_POST['First_Name'];   
$last_name=$_POST['Last_Name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO pax (First_Name, Last_Name, email)
VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$email')"); 

//send age checkbox data to age database table
$age = $_POST['age'];
$my_range = "";
foreach($age as $range)
$my_range = $my_range . $range . " ";
//You have written this query wrong
mysql_query("INSERT INTO age(age) VALUES ('$my_range')") or die (mysql_error());

mysql_close($dbc);
```

While retrieving it from the database you can use expode() to get each age range...Here is the sample code

```
$range_string = "20-25 26-30 31-35";
$range_array = explode(" ", $range_string);
echo $range_array [0]; // 20-25
echo $range_array [1]; // 26-30
echo $range_array [2]; // 31-35
```

You might also want to look at http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html for some information on checkboxes...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help and the sitelink (I think I google searched this for three days and didn't come across that site previosuly).  I entered your coding as suggested and got the following error message:  Unknown column 'age' in 'field list'     The mysql table is 'age' (without quotes); so, I'm at a loss as to why it can't understand the html coding name="age[]".

Comment: should I be taking out id="20-25", etc for each in the list as this is controlled by value?   To clarify:  the table 'age' has the following fields ...  age_id, pax_id (which is an index for the text field data at the beginning of the form), then the age ranges as separate fields ... 20-25, 26-30 and so on.

Comment: I'm just wanting the code to put a '1' in the age range selected within the checkbox form.

Comment: YES!  That was the deal, the table should not be with fields for each age range and then just tick each range as it is selected but let the checkbox inseert the selected age range into the table as associated by the user id.  Many thanks to  Riten for help with the code and leading me the right direction.  It now works!!!

Answer (score 1):

before you try to actually run mysql queries, you should test to make sure the queries youre constructing have the correct information in them.

You could do something like this to quickly check:

```
foreach($age as $range) {
    print "INSERT INTO age ($age) VALUES ('$range')";
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be sticking `$_POST` data straight into your queries, someone could easily write SQL code into a field and delete your database. Look up the topic of "mysql input sanitation"

Comment: thanks - will keep the print code in mind.  I'm not so worried about sql injection ... it's going to remain localhost in an office of people that barely know excel much less sql.

Comment: inexperienced computer users and hacky people will probably have a similar effect -- they'll eventually break your text fields by having a character that will break the form